# Minimum for varchar?

Tags: mysql

I thought you could set varchar as varchar(min,max), but I must have mistaken. What's the syntax to set a min and max? Or do I have to use PHP to do that?

**Update:**
Let me add more context. I'm making a field for usernames, so I thought I could set the minimum and maximum for varchar in MySQL. Seems I can only set the length which is 0 to 255. I'm guessing this means I have to use PHP to add the minimum restriction

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot set a minimum length for a VARCHAR field in MySQL. Despite jspcal's answer, there is no such min length constraint.

The max is simply VARCHAR(max)

Yes, you must use PHP to limit the length. Personally, I use application code to perform all my constraint validations, and only rely on the DB as a last resort/failsafe.

It's better to detect invalid data in your application and return a useful error message, than to catch a DB exception and have to interpret/translate that into the appropriate error message.

Comment: "you must use PHP to limit the length" - this is *false*. obviously you've never heard of triggers, which is how mysql implements constraints: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers#Emulating_Check_Constraints. read and learn.

Comment: First, your link is outdated. It shows page not found error. Although there might be case where applying the constraint in triggers is better. Most Web framework like Django has implemented the checks for min length. It is certainly easier to implement in your service as well.

Answer (score 2):

better to do it in php, mysql would require some triggers to do the constraints.

Comment: There are constraints under MySQL?

Comment: Your original answer was "Yes you can do it with constraints". You completely changed the body of your answer to CYA.

Comment: @hobodave: you're *completely wrong*. obviously you've never heard of triggers (http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers#Emulating_Check_Constraints) which is how mysql implements constraints. read and learn before you downvote incorrectly.